# Selenium: cssSelector and path both cannot find an element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

So I've tried to select this element by both cssSelector and Xpath but no luck. It returns the error no such element. But this is the closest i've gotten to grabbing the element with the below code.

```
WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("meta[property='og\\:title']"));
```

or

```
WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@property='og\\:title']"));
```

However, it still provides the error of invalid selector or no such element.

The Xpath I've tried is below. The element is below. If you want to the website it is also below.

```
/html/head/meta[14]
```

HTML:

```
<meta property="og:title" content=" Blydenburgh County Park Stump Pond Loop" class="xlate-none">
```

URL: [www.alltrails.com/explore/trail/us/new-york/blydenburgh-county-park-stump-pond-loop](http://www.alltrails.com/explore/trail/us/new-york/blydenburgh-county-park-stump-pond-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary symbols `\\` after `og`. So your code can't find the path. Try like this

```
WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@property='og:title']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as **Blydenburgh County Park Stump Pond Loop** within the url https://www.alltrails.com/explore/trail/us/new-york/blydenburgh-county-park-stump-pond-loop?u=m, as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.alltrails.com/explore/trail/us/new-york/blydenburgh-county-park-stump-pond-loop?u=m");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe#trail-details-frame")));
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h1[title=' Blydenburgh County Park Stump Pond Loop']")));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.alltrails.com/explore/trail/us/new-york/blydenburgh-county-park-stump-pond-loop?u=m");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='trail-details-frame']")));
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[@title=' Blydenburgh County Park Stump Pond Loop']")));
  ```